# Status bar in single view hide/ style

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, statusbar

in my app I've multiple views . I need to hide the status bar for one view ( this vC2 is in order navigationC -> VC ->push to vC2) . it works firstly by setting 
 `View controller-based status bar appearance = NO` in plist

and then use 
`[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;` in the viewWillAppear 
and  `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = NO;` in viewWillDisappear 
to reback the status bar.

Then , I want to set the status bar with light colour style for another single view (VC3) in the same app. only one way works with me is 
by setting  `View controller-based status bar appearance = YES` and use

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

in the VC3.m 
my problem is around `View controller-based status bar appearance` which used with NO value for hiding status bar and used with YES value for light style of status bar

Can I combine the the hiding / and style status bar in my app?

My target is iOS7

Answer (score 0):

YOu can by using this function in viewController:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

The plist boolean has to be YES and you can add something more:

Try

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]
```

And in case you have view controllers as childs of other viewControllers, the last child is the one that should decide

If the VC is child of another VC (this on the first level VC that you subclass, not need if you are using a navigation without subclassing)

```
- (UIViewController *)childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden {
     return _myChildViewController;
}
```

Comment: I already tried this , the status bar still appearing . is there something need to be added to view or in the plist?

Comment: have you any special configuration of VC?

Comment: No,  I think.. like what special configuration?

Comment: By setting tge plist to YES,  i lose the hiding prperty for status bar

Comment: By setting Plist to yes you have to control the behavior for each VC. The only way I'm finding difficult to controll is when I have an architecture of navigationC -> PageViewC -> VC

Comment: You mean when VC is children ? My VC I want to hide its status bar is like u , its navigationC -> VC -> VC ,is it possible to do what you explained?

Comment: Additionally. If your CV uses xib, you can set on the Simulated Metrics the status bar None

Comment: I also did that but nothing change... I appreciate your help